# Parseval's (Plancherel's) identity for Hilbert space-valued operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, parsevals-identity

Let $\mathcal H$ be a (separable) Hilbert space on $\mathbb C$.

Suppose $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi), \mathcal H)$ and $c_n$ is n-th Fourier coefficient of $f$, i.e., $c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-in x}\ f(x)dx.$

Show that if $B:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$ be a bounded operator, we have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\|B (c_n)\|_{\mathcal H}^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \|B(f(x))\|_{\mathcal H}^2 dx.$$

I'm having difficulty in showing this.

Somehow I think we can use :

for $g\in \mathcal H$, $(\int f(x)dx, g)_{\mathcal H}=\int(f(x),g)_{\mathcal H}dx$ and
$(g, \int f(x)dx)_{\mathcal H}=\int(g,f(x))_{\mathcal H}dx$ hold.
(These are already proven.)

e.g., I may have
$$\|B(c_n)\|^2
=(B(c_n),B(c_n))
=(B(\int e^{-inx}f(x)dx), B(c_n))
=(\int B( e^{-inx}f(x))dx, B(c_n))
=\int (e^{-inx}B(f(x)), B(c_n)) dx
=\int e^{inx}(B(f(x)), B(c_n)) dx
$$ (although I don't know whether I can push integral outside of $B$. )

I'm stacked because I don't know how I should do for this identity, how I should handle infinite sum. I also searched solutions but I've not found yet.

Does anyone have idea for proving the identity ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: how is the integration defined in this case

Comment: Maybe, the integral for $f$ is Bochner integral (integral for Banach space-valued function). @sb945

Comment: This result should follow from Parseval's identity and the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: If you already have $\sum_n \|c_n(f)\|_\mathcal{H}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2}^2$ for all $f \in L^2$, then you can reach the conclusion easily by using the fact that $B\left(c_n(f)\right) = c_n\left(B \circ f\right)$. That's because you can indeed "push" $B$ inside or outside of integrals and conserve equality.

Comment: As for proving Parseval's identity (the first equality I wrote), I don't know what to do if $\mathcal{H}$ is not separable, but if it is then, taking an orthormal basis $(u_m)_m$, you might be able to show that $(g_{m,n})_{m,n} := \left(x \mapsto e^{inx} u_m\right)_{m,n}$ is (up to normalisation) an orthonormal basis of $L^2([-\pi,\pi), \mathcal{H})$, and then write $\|c_n[f]\|^2$ as $\sum_m \|f_{m,n} g_{m,n}\|_{L^2}^2$ where $f =: \sum_{m,n} f_{m,n} g_{m,n}$ maybe? Then you'd be able to just summon Parseval-Plancherel for separable Hilbert spaces.

Comment: O.K. Thanks for the comment. $\mathcal H$ is assumed to be separable now, and I already have Parseval's identity for $L^2.$ So I need $B(c_nf)=c_n(B\circ f).$ I haven't seen why we can change $B$ and integral sign. Are there some explanation or references ? @BrunoB

Comment: That's a property of the Bochner integral which is applicable since $B$ is linear and bounded.

Comment: A reference I can give is the chapter $11$ from *Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide* by Aliprantis and Border: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03004-2. Specifically Theorem $11.50$ towards the beginning of the Gelfand integral part. Since we're considering a Hilbert space, which is isomorphic to its dual, the difference between Gelfand, Pettis and Dunford integrals should be pretty minor.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll check in the library. @BrunoB